# Updating User and its user profile in django

Tags: python, django

How to I bind User fields data and user profile data to a model form on my view, I only get user data rendered to a form when i use instance=user but it doesn't render any data of user profile on instance=profile, what i need is to render all user and its profile to a form.

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
is_supervisor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Supervisor(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='supervisor')
su_mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**view.py**

```
def supervisor_update(request, user_id):
# user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
profile = get_object_or_404(Supervisor, pk=user_id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SupervisorSignUpForm(request.POST, instance=user)
else:
    form = SupervisorSignUpForm(instance=user)
return save_user_form(request, form, 'partials/partial_supervisor_update.html')
```

**form.py**

```
class SupervisorSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
su_mobile_number = forms.CharField(label="Mobile Number")

class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

**supervisor_update.html**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'supervisor_update' form.instance.pk %}" class="js-supervisor-update-form">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Update Supervisor</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  {% include 'partials/form_messages.html' %}



    {{ form.username|as_crispy_field }}

    {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}


    {{ form.first_name|as_crispy_field }}

    {{ form.last_name|as_crispy_field }}

    {{ form.su_mobile_number|as_crispy_field }}


    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Supervisor</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the extra field passing in initial along with the user instance should work

```
    initial = {'su_mobile_number': profile.su_mobile_number}
    form = SupervisorSignUpForm(instance=user, initial=initial)
```

Or if you dont want to manually create the dict you could use model_to_dict

```
    from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
    initial = model_to_dict(profile, exclude=['user'])
    form = SupervisorSignUpForm(instance=user, initial=initial)
```

Also at the top of your view you are assuming user and supervisor have the same id which could not be the case instead you could do something like this

```
    user = user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    profile = user.supervisor
    if not profile:
        raise Http404
```

Comment: thnx for the reply, the problem i have is in supervisor_update.html the data value for su_mobile_number does not display on the field but other associated with User model works

Comment: I get error form = SupervisorSignUpForm(instance=user, initial) SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument in initial

Comment: i changed the position of arguments form = SupervisorSignUpForm(initial, instance=user) but it doesnt work

Comment: My bad it should be SupervisorSignUpForm(initial=initial, instance=user). Just  updated the answer